# How can i trigger zendesk web widget after page reload?

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api

I create custom ticket form in zendesk and passing some parameters (like customer name, customer email, and customers company name) from my database. then i found zE(identify) functions and saw this functions include just name and email object. but i need customers company names too. and it is just came after completely page reload.

So how can i refresh (or something) after database value completely reload?

sorry for my bad english

Comment: how are you detecting the database value reload, and are you looking to refresh the entire web page, or just execute the zE(identify) function again?

Comment: when page reload finished then comes database value. i want to execute whole web widget after page reload finished. zE(identify) function not usefull for me (i think) because its include just two object like name and email. because i am looking for different solution for company name.

Comment: actually i need, how can i update or trigger custom ticket fields value in spa project?

Comment: is company name the Zendesk user organization value, or is it a custom field?

Comment: company name is a custom field. i added especially. but i didnt connect custom fields into the db company value. zE(identify) function doesnt need to reload the page. but i cant connect my custom field to identify function. i am not sure clearly tell:(

Comment: It appears that setting dropdown fields via the API is not supported - https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/widget/settings#fields,  so you may want to consider using the organization parameter of the zE(identify).  Any reason you prefer custom field instead?

Answer (score 0):

To execute zE function after page load you should be able to add it to a callback function from however you are loading the DB values.